# Character being assigned to a specific Hex Value / Decimal Value

Tags: java, android

Right now, I'm a bit confused on how assignment works. 
In my code, there isn't any assignment of variable to hex value or etc.

So right now when print out the data of msg.getBytes, I get values of my characters.
I sent the string, "Temasek" and what I got in return was "84 101 109 97 115 101 107".
So in sequence starting from T till K, each letter is represented by the decimal value.

What I don't get is, how are these decimal value assigned to the characters? I've been working on the code for days and I can't find which method or which line that is assigning the characters with these decimal values.

The main point that I want to understand is, how do I assign the values manually or are the values assigned in the readThread method?

I need to change the values as to match my MC Side because I've set the values of each character in my MicroController Side differently.

So an example is, instead of T = 84(0x54), I want it to be T = 52(0x34).

This is the **Logcat**:

```
07-21 17:02:05.500: I/System.out(16827): 84
07-21 17:02:05.500: I/System.out(16827): 101
07-21 17:02:05.500: I/System.out(16827): 109
07-21 17:02:05.500: I/System.out(16827): 97
07-21 17:02:05.500: I/System.out(16827): 115
07-21 17:02:05.500: I/System.out(16827): 101
07-21 17:02:05.500: I/System.out(16827): 107
07-21 17:02:05.507: I/System.out(16827): Mode: 1
07-21 17:02:05.507: I/Tag(16827): TextSetting[0] = 100
```

This is my **SendMessageHandle Method**:

```
private void sendMessageHandle(String msg) {

    final byte ANIMATION_MODE=3;
    final byte PICTURE_MODE=2;
    final byte TEXT_MODE=1;
    final String PAUSE = "\r";

    int temp,row;

    sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("storeData",MODE_PRIVATE);

    byte mode = (byte) sPrefs.getInt("Mode",1);
    byte [] pictureData = new byte [129];
    byte [] textSetting =new byte [5];

    if (socket == null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        if(mode==TEXT_MODE){
            byte[] buf = msg.getBytes();
            textSetting[0]=100;
            textSetting[1]=(byte) sPrefs.getInt("directionData", '1');
            textSetting[2]=(byte) sPrefs.getInt("positionData", '1');
            textSetting[3]=(byte) sPrefs.getInt("speedSeekBar", 10);
            if(sPrefs.getBoolean("checkBox1", true)){
                textSetting[4]=1 ;                          
            }
            else
                textSetting[4]=0 ;

            os.write(textSetting);  
            os.write(msg.getBytes());
            for(int i = 0; i<buf.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(buf[i]);
            }

        }
```

This my **clientThread Method**:

```
private class clientThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {

            try {
                //
                bdDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BlueToothAddress);
                socket = bdDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                Message msg2 = new Message();
                msg2.obj = "Please wait, connecting to server: "
                        + BlueToothAddress;
                msg2.what = 0;
                LinkDetectedHandler.sendMessage(msg2);
            //  System.out.println(socket + "|mac:" + BlueToothAddress);
                socket.connect();

                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "Device connected. Sending message is allowed.";
                msg.what = 0;
                LinkDetectedHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                //
                readThread = new readThread();
                readThread.start();
                click++;
                //contentEV.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                // Enable the openBtn,closeBtn£¬discoverBtn
                //discoverBtn.setClickable(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            //  System.out.println("Exception");
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "Error! Can't connect to device. Please try again.";
                msg.what = 0;
                LinkDetectedHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                click--;
                //contentEV.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                // Enable the openBtn,closeBtn£¬discoverBtn
                //discoverBtn.setClickable(true);
            }
        }
    };
```

This is my **readThread Method**:

```
private class readThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            InputStream mmInStream = null;
            String tmp = null;
            try {
                mmInStream = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // read the data from the inputStream 
                    if ((bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer)) > 0) 
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
                            tmp = "" + buffer[i];
                            String st = new String(tmp);
                            tmp = null;
                            Message msg = new Message();
                            msg.obj = st;
                            msg.what = 1;

                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        mmInStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @JamesB - I know, that those are the default values. But in my MicroCntroller Side, it is set manually. Is there a way I can set manually in the Android Side?

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc:

> public byte[] getBytes()
>
> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's
>   default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

hence when you call getBytes by default your 'T' is encoded as 0x54 (See full table here: http://unicode-table.com/en/ ) If you want something else write your own getBytes() function.

Comment: So are you saying, by default it follows the universal ASCII Table? If I want to change it manually, I have to create a whole new method full of array list?

Comment: What is your requirements for the vew values? You said you want 52 instead of 84 for T but what about other chars? Is it a simple translation (ascii code -32) which would be easy to code?

Comment: Yes, just simple conversion. Different char will represent different value that is all. Nothing complicated. Only different ascii table. Is there any reference on how to create my own charset?

Answer (score 0):

There are variants of the `getBytes` method where you can specify the `Charset` to be used for the encoding. If you need to use a charset not provided with the platform you will have to implement it yourself. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) for the details.

Comment: By chance, is there any links/reference on creating your own charset?

Answer (score 0):

Java uses internally Unicode, so it may combine all scripts of the world. Unicode is a numbering of all characters upto a number in the 3-byte range. It has several byte representations, most important: multi-byte UTF-8, multi-word UTF-16LE, UTF16-BE.

In Unicode `a` has code U+61 (hexadecimal) which is 97 decimal or `\u0061` (as you may write in java).

- A one-to-one Unicode usage is to use a java **code point**, `int`, 32 bits.
- Java internally made a compromise and uses UTF-16 `char`, 16 bits.
  Sometimes needing needing several chars to represent one code point.
- Binary data is in `byte[]` which always is in some encoding.

So there is a separation between text (internally, hidden, Unicode):

- String, char
- Reader, Writer

and binary data:

- byte[]
- InputStream, OutputStream

The binary data needs some encoding to be interpreted as text.

- new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, encoding)
- new InputStreamReader(inputStream, encoding)
- new String(bytes, encoding)
- String.getBytes(encoding)

These methods unfortunately are overloaded with a version *without* encoding, taking the default platform encoding. Which is not portable.

Now if you search for ASCII, ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) and Windows-1252 (Windows Latin-1) you will see `a` always being number 97 as in Unicode.

***Answer***:

The bytes are a conversion of the Unicode characters, in your case using the operating system encoding. In this case the conversion was an identity mapping. But try `ĉeĥo` ("Czech" in Esperanto).

```
String s = "\u0109e\u0125o"; // "ĉeĥo"
s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); // Not representable
s.getBy\u0074es("Windows-1252"); // Not representable
```